# Check two arrays keys and bring array 2 value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, they are formatted like so:

Array 1 (string turned into an array):

```
$super = 'aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff';
$array = explode(", ", $super);
```

Array 2:

```
$email = array(
    "bb" => "email1", 
    "aa" => "email2", 
    "dd" => "email3", 
    "cc" => "email4", 
    "ee" => "email5", 
    "ff" => "email6"
);
```

The goal is to check array one against the `ids` on array 2 and if they do match, return their value i.e `email1, email2 etc..`

My attempt:

```
foreach($array as $index => $arra) {
    echo 'code: ' . $arra . ' array' . $email[$index] . 'list';
}
```

It brings back the following:

```
code: aa arraylistcode: bb arraylistcode: cc arraylistcode: dd arraylistcode: ee arraylistcode: ff arraylist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each piece of `$array` should be the key to be used in `$email` array:

```
foreach($array as $index => $arra) {
    if(isset($email[$arra])) { // check if this key exist
        echo 'code: ' . $arra . ' email: ' . $email[$arra] . '<br/>';
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One line approach

```
$result = array_intersect_key($email, array_flip($array));
var_dump($result);
```

`array_flip` turns array to ['aa'=>0, 'bb'=>1, ...];

`array_intersect_key` keeps values from email array only if flipped array has the same key

[array_flip](http://php.net/array_flip), [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/array_intersect_key)